# How can I make calculation pieces in PHP?

Tags: php, percentage

How can I make calculation pieces in PHP?

This is my calculation

```
605,00 / 5% = 30.25.
```

How can I calculate this in PHP?

```
$a = 605.00;
$b = 5 (percentage)
```

How I have tried, but this did not work

```
$total = ($a / 0.5);
```

Comment: Well 0.5 is 50%, not 5%, and you'd want to multiply rather than divide: mathematics 101 - `$total = ($a * $b / 100);`

Comment: And dividing by 0.5 means multiplying by 2.

Comment: you could always try: `$a * ($b / 100);` you know...

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
$number = 605;
$percentage = 5;
$total = $number  * ($percentage / 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you divide 5 by 100, it will equal `0.05` so try `$b = .05;`.

In basic math, the first decimal is calculated in 10ths, then 100ths, then 1000ths

Just do `$total = ($a / $b);`

Tested. **Total = 12,100** yet will echo `12100`

```
<?php

$a = 605.00;
$b = 0.05;

$total = ($a / $b);

echo $total; // will echo 12100

?>
```